# Porque chamam a maconha de "baseado"? Qual a origem desse termo?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, etimologia, expressões, origem-histórica

Tenho curiosidade de saber a origem da palavra "baseado" atribuída à droga.

Comment: Joao, como já há uma pergunta sobre a origem de "beck", removi esta parte, mas deixei a sobre a origem de "baseado", que não creio que já tenha sido feita.

Comment: Curiosamente, em Portugal, não se usa nenhuma das formas. Usamos CANÁBIS, MARIJUANA, HAXIXE ou até mesmo «ERVA».

Comment: @JorgeB. Esses nomes também são usados no Brasil, mas para a planta ou seu fumo, enquanto "baseado" é especificamente seu cigarro.

Comment: @stafusa aqui é CHARRO ou BROCA para o seu cigarro.